# Linker errors trying to use shapelib

Tags: c++, shapefile, lnk2001

I am trying to include shapelib in an existing solution in MSVS 2010. However, I'm getting the following errors for each function call from shapelib:

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "extern "C" void __clrcall SHPDestroyObject(struct SHPObject *)" (?SHPDestroyObject@@$$J0YMXPEAUSHPObject@@@Z)    *.obj
```

So far what I've done was include the "shapefil.h" file in the *.cpp file (the same file name which gives the error for the *.obj). Also, I've added

```
$(SolutionDir)$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\shapelib.lib
```

to Project->Properties->Configuration Properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies. What should I do to fix this issue? I'm fairly new including external libraries so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you forgot to wrap the include of shapefil.h to extern "C"?

Comment: At the top of shapefil.h is: 
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
Is this what you mean?

Comment: I ment mostly in your source file, but this seems slightly same. Perhaps then you could show the exact command lines to the compiller and linker?

Comment: I think I fixed it using a work around. I erased the shapelib.lib from the additional dependencies and included shpopen.c and safileio.c into my project. Didn't get any errors at least.